# 5 geometric shapes, all touching each other

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, planar-graphs

I was playing aroud with shapes, which all connected. I managed to get 3 and 4 shapes all connected to each other, but I can't get 5 to work in 2D.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what these shapes are called and also how to get 5 shapes connected? It would be the best, if all shapes were congruent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to make five 2D shapes (on a flat plane) which all touch each other. This is a consequence of the [four color map theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_map_theorem).

Comment: Appealing to the four-color theorem seems heavy-handed. It's just the statement that $K_5$ isn't planar.

Answer (score 9):

If it were possible to have 5 shapes in the plane, all touching each other, then if you drew a vertex in the center of each shape and connected the vertices, you would get a [Planar drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) of the [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) $K_5$. A standard elementary result in graph theory (and simply proven, unlike the very difficult four-color theorem) is that $K_5$ is not planar (see for example [these notes](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/graphtheory-F11/planar.pdf)). So it is impossible.