# Highest number of objects touching each other in 3D

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Suppose I have a couple of identical cuboids (think lego bricks). I can arrange four of them so that each one touches all the other. Is four already the maximum? What if other *identical* objects are allowed?

In 2d this is related to [5 geometric shapes, all touching each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550054/5-geometric-shapes-all-touching-each-other) and hence the 4-color-theorem.

In 3d I found this demonstrator for the 4-color-theorem: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AnInfinitelyColorableSetOf3DRegions/ . It misses the point though: The cuboids on the same plane don't touch each other.

Surface area needs to be > 0.

First post, willing to learn.

Comment: The demo is spot on. It is you who misses the point here. Their shapes are **not** cuboids. Look at that cross-like thing composed of two sticks of the same color. That's _one_ of their objects. They are not quite identical, but that can be fixed easily.

Comment: Thanks @IvanNeretin, now it makes way more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the demo you linked to.

For given $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ consider the shape
$$S_0 = [-n,n] \times [0,1) \times [0,1] \cup [0,1) \times [-n,n] \times [-1,0]$$
which is connected since the two cuboids share the set $[0,1)\times[0,1)\times\{0\}$.
Now define
$$S_k = \{(x+k,y+k,z)|(x,y,z)\in S_0\}$$
which is just the same shape translated by the vector $(k,k,0)^T$.

Now obviously for $0<=j,k<n$, the sets $S_j$ and $S_k$ touch each other at $[j,j+1)\times[k,k+1)\times\{0\}$. Therefore you need to least $n$ colours.

Since $n$ was arbitrary, this means that there's no finite set of colours allowing to colour all sets of identical shapes.